# Can I change the properties of all files to show info similar to the folder templates properties?

Tags: properties

I use Windows Explorer every day to manage large groups of files. I modified the folder templates in Windows 7 to display the properties that are important to me. (Ex: Name, size, length, date created, contributing artists). I now want all the individual files to have these same properties whenever I open a folder which has files of that type (Ex: whenever there is a music file in .mp3 format, the template for music files that I created are displayed in Windows Explorer). How do I change the individual music files all at one time so the properties values I want to see are displayed in Windows Explorer? (instead of seeing rating, date modified, etc. I want to see the properties that match those for the folder level).

Answer (score 0):

I just tested a theory on my machine. I changed the details shown to date created, date modified, bit rate, and size, while in my itunes parent folder. The properties seemed to be carried down the child folders. SO now all of my child folders under itunes with music in them, now display date created, date modified, bit rate, and size. Instead of number, album, and title. Also if you go into your music through c:\users\XXXXX it is the same format as the rest of the drive. But if you go to your music through libraries it saves its properties for details shown per library, so in that case it is unique to that library only and is unaffected by the "Apply to all folders" button.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to set the list of properties that needs to be displayed for all MP3 Folders. I use Windows Vista. This is what I did and I am able to see the same properties displayed for all folders:

You will need to first set the MP3 Folder Type as Music Details:

1. Go to a MP3 Folder on explorer and right click and choose properties,
2. Go To Customize Option,
3. There is a drop down called *Use this folder type as template*. Under this choose the option - Music details. This step will set the folder type as Music Details.

Steps to choose the properties that needs to be displayed for a MP3 Folder:

1. Now choose the MP3 Folder on Windows Explorer. The type of the folder should be Music details,
2. Go to right pane on explorer. Right Click on one of the properties like name, title etc and choose the More Option and choose all the details you want to be displayed for a MP3 folder. Save
3. This is the main step:

   - Go to Windows Explorer Organize Option,
   - Choose Folder and Search Option,
   - Go to View Tab,
   - Click on *Apply To All Folders* option - Explorer will ask you to confirm the current view for all Music Details folder - Choose Yes,
   - You will see that for all MP3 folders now you have the same properties like Name, Title, Size, Album etc. displayed

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to set the list of properties that needs to be displayed for all MP3 Folders. I use Windows Vista. This is what I did and I am able to see the same properties displayed for all folders now:

FIRST STEP - Set the MP3 Folder Type as (Music Details). For this perform steps A, B, & C.

A) Go to a MP3 Folder on windows explorer and right click and choose (PROPERTIES)

B) Go  to (CUSTOMIZE)  option

C) There is a drop down called  (WHAT KIND OF FOLDER DO YOU WWANT? USE THIS FOLDER TYPE AS TEMPLATE ). Under this Drop Down choose (MUSIC DETAILS)  and press (OK). This step will set the folder type as Music Details. You can also apply this property to all sub folders by ticking the option (ALSO APPLY THIS TEMPLATE TO ALL SUB FOLDERS)

SECOND STEP - Choose the properties that needs to be displayed for a MP3 Folder. For this perform Step D, E & F.

D) Choose the MP3 Folder on Windows Explorer. Note, the type of the folder should be Music details (Refer Step ABC to set a folder of type Music Details). If needed place 2 or 3 MP3 files in this folder

E) Go to right pane on explorer.  You will see some MP3 properties displayed in columns default by explorer. Right Click on one of the MP3 properties like Name or Title etc and choose the (MORE) Option. Choose all the details you want to be displayed for a MP3 folder – Arrange it using (UP) and (DOWN) buttons – Press (OK) to save properties

F)This is the main important step - Go to Windows Explorer (ORGANIZE) Option (This step could be different for XP, Vista, Windows 7) but a similar option is there in all the three OS - Choose (FOLDER AND SEARCH OPTIONS) – You will see 3 TABS – General, View , Search. Now, Go To (VIEW) Tab - Click on  (APPLY TO ALL FOLDERS OPTION)  - Explorer will ask you to confirm the current view for all Music Details folders - Choose (YES)

G) You will see that for all MP3 folders now display same properties like Name, Title, Size, Album etc whih you chose

Hope this helps Cheers